# time not defined, why?

Tags: python, variables, python-3.6

Im very new to python. Trying to do exercises from various books. The following code was working until I broke it in to sections to make functions.  Why are the variables no longer recognized? This happens often to me at this point.

```
def pay_param():
    while True:
        try:
            time = int(input('Enter Hours: '))
        except:
            print('please enter a number')
            continue
        break
    while True:
        try:
            wage = int(input('Enter Wage: '))
        except:
            print('please enter a number')
            continue
        break

def computepay():
    pay_param()
    ot = time - 40

    if time >= 41:
        pay = (40 * wage) + (1.5 * wage * ot)
    elif time < 41:
        pay = time * (wage)
    print(pay)

computepay()
```

Comment: time is a local in pay_param

Comment: Your question title triggered the physicist in me. Now disappointed.

Comment: Actually time doesn't exist clock does!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a return value to `pay_param`

```
return time, wage
```

and you can get the values:

```
time, wage = pay_param()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the time variable is defined in the first function `pay_param()` and only accessible within its scope (i.e. you cannot access it in the other function). I propose you return the wage and time variables.

Answer (score 0):

You want to read about [variable scopes](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html). Because your 'time' variable is used within the function, it cannot be accessed outside of the function. It's a `local variable` within the function's scope.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `time` and `wage` are local variables. The are not inside `pay_param`'s scope. [Maybe give this a quick read](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php).

You can return the input in order to have acces to the values. For example:

```
def pay_param(prompt_message):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt_message))
        except:
            print('please enter a number')
            continue

def computepay():

    time = pay_param('Enter Hours: ')
    wage = pay_param('Enter Wage: ')

    ot = time - 40

    if time >= 41:
        pay = (40 * wage) + (1.5 * wage * ot)
    elif time < 41:
        pay = time * (wage)
    print(pay)

computepay()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, Python does not know what is `time` when it encounters this statement `ot = time - 40` (similarly, `wage`). You assigned to `time` in a function and its scope remains local to that function only. What you need is to return to function caller.

```
def pay_param():
    while True:
        # ......
        break
    return time, wage
```

In `computepay()`, you need to receive the returned value like so:

```
def computepay():
    time, wage = pay_param()
    ot = time - 40
    # Rest code as it is...
```